# How to get dynamic paramter in asp.net mvc post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, dynamic

I'm trying to make some of my post methods like this:

Client Side:

```
$.post("/control/PostMethod",{a:1,b:2,c:[1,2,3],d:{x:1,y:0}})
```

Server Side:

```
[HttpPost]
public int PostMethod(dynamic model)
{
    //do something with model.a model.b etc.
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is if I did nothing,the model seems to be one simple object with no property,so i tried to write a `CustomModelBinder` replace `DefaultModelBinder` and override the `CreateModel` method by analyse form values.But I found it became very difficult because the properties had been expanded,like the property `d` became `a[d][x],a[d][y]` in form values.

So is there any simple way to transfer client post data to a dynamic object in actions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to also supply information about the type you could use a custom model binder and supply the necessary type infos. I have a modelbinder that scans for a "type" querystring-value that is used to feed the modelbinder with the information it needs.

```
 public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
        {
            public override object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
            {
                // Check if the model type is object
                if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof( object ))
                {

                    // Try to get type info from the query string or form-data
                    var type = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["type"] ??
                            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["type"];

                        if (type != null )
                        {
                            // Find a way to get type info, for example
                               var matchingType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(type);

                            // Supply the metadata for our bindingcontext and the default binder will do the rest
                            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType( null, matchingType );


    }
            }

            return base.BindModel( controllerContext, bindingContext );
        }
    }
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Method( string type, object model )
{
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use dynamic not an exist type.